# multi-line input using list comprehension in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm working on a python challenge question where I have to get 2nd highest value in a sublist. My code works fine but I wanted to see if I could shorten it. Mainly I want to create a list with sublists for the input. This was achieved with a for loop, but I'm sure I could get the same result with list comprehension. The comment is the code is my first failed attempt.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    grade = []
#   m = [[input(), float(input())]] for _ in range(int(input()))]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        peeps= [name, score]
    grade.append(peeps)
    print(sorted(grade, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1][0])
```

Also I was wondering if the print statement could be written with list comprehension instead of importing operator and slicing.

Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra bracket in the list-comp. `m = [[input(), float(input())] for _ in range(int(input()))]` works just fine.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a name; that name is already used for the respective data structure.

Comment: Fixed the list and thanks for pointing out the offending bracket

Comment: indentation of `grade.append(peeps)` looks wrong.

Comment: @jq170727 Is definitely wrong, should be indented. Good catch!